# Get DIV height from c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get the height of rendered DIV without using JavaScript?

Reason is using the following code to get return html of a page but none of JavaScript fires:

```
Server.Execute(url, htmlStringWriter);
string htmlCodeToConvert = htmlStringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

Comment: Not with that class. A browser has to interpret the the HTML/CSS to create the dom.

Comment: Which browser are you running this HTML in?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, no it is not possible. The philosophy behind HTML has always been that browsers have some freedom of choice in rendering it. So no, you cannot predict what the user's browser is going to do with your div.